# PHP 5.4.29 anonymous functions callback error

Tags: php, callback, anonymous-function, php-5.4

I cannot resolve an issue with PHP 5.4.29 since few days...
I want to use anonymous functions with the core library functions but it seems to create an error. Anonymous functions were introduced in PHP 5.3 so I think the PHP version is not the source of the problem.

Here's the code :

```
array_sum(array_map(function ($element) {return ($element["price"]);}, $_SESSION["cart"]))
```

And here's the warning generated by PHP :

```
PHP Warning:  array_map() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, no array or string given
```

What is very strange is that this error only happen on one server, I have another server with PHP 5.4.27 and everything works well.

Let me know if you know how to fix this error.

Thank you

Comment: On the server that it's failing on, have you done a PHP upgrade recently to that server? Or at least attempted to?

Comment: Yes, I have updated from PHP 5.2, and it seems to be installed because in phpinfo() the version is 5.4.29.

Comment: Hmm...ok. Because I've seen a scenario before where (on a Windows machine) the environment variable PATH pointed to the new PHP folder, so if you did `php -v` on a terminal, it would say the new version. However, the httpd.conf file in the apache folder was still pointing to the old PHP location (because we had to revert back a version). It doesn't seem like you have that issue, though.